# How do I extract all the text in a bibliography that is within quotation marks in R?

Tags: r, text, extract

I need to extract the journal titles from a bibliography list. The titles are all within quotation marks.
So is there a way to ask R to extract all text that is within parenthesis?

I have read the list into R as a text file:

"data <- readLines("Publications _ CCDM.txt")"

here are a few lines from the list:

Andronis, C.E., Hane, J., Bringans, S., Hardy, G., Jacques, S., Lipscombe, R., Tan, K-C. (2020). “Gene validation and remodelling using proteogenomics of Phytophthora cinnamomi, the causal agent of Dieback.” bioRxiv. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1101/2020.10.25.354530
Beccari, G., Prodi, A., Senatore, M.T., Balmas, V,. Tini, F., Onofri, A., Pedini, L., Sulyok, M,. Brocca, L., Covarelli, L. (2020). “Cultivation Area Affects the Presence of Fungal Communities and Secondary Metabolites in Italian Durum Wheat Grains.” Toxins  https://www.mdpi.com/2072-6651/12/2/97
Corsi, B., Percvial-Alwyn, L., Downie, R.C., Venturini, L., Iagallo, E.M., Campos Mantello, C., McCormick-Barnes, C., See, P.T., Oliver, R.P., Moffat, C.S., Cockram, J. “Genetic analysis of wheat sensitivity to the ToxB fungal effector from Pyrenophora tritici-repentis, the causal agent of tan spot” Theoretical and Applied Genetics. https://doi.org/10.1007/s00122-019-03517-8
Derbyshire, M.C., (2020) Bioinformatic Detection of Positive Selection Pressure in Plant Pathogens: The Neutral Theory of Molecular Sequence Evolution in Action. (2020) Frontiers in Microbiology. https://doi.org/10.3389/fmicb.2020.00644
Dodhia, K.N., Cox, B.A., Oliver, R.P., Lopez-Ruiz, F.J. (2020). “When time really is money: in situ quantification of the strobilurin resistance mutation G143A in the wheat pathogen Blumeria graminis f. sp. tritici.” bioRxiv, doi: https://doi.org/10.1101/2020.08.20.258921
Graham-Taylor, C., Kamphuis, L.G., Derbyshire, M.C. (2020). “A detailed in silico analysis of secondary metabolite biosynthesis clusters in the genome of the broad host range plant pathogenic fungus Sclerotinia sclerotiorum.” BMC Genomics https://doi.org/10.1186/s12864-019-6424-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "“.*?”") %>% .[[1]]
```

if you want to remove quotation from result add this at the end of pipeline:

```
str_remove_all("[“”]")
```

Output:

```
[1] "Gene validation and remodelling using proteogenomics of Phytophthora cinnamomi, the causal agent of Dieback."                                                       
[2] "Cultivation Area Affects the Presence of Fungal Communities and Secondary Metabolites in Italian Durum Wheat Grains."                                               
[3] "Genetic analysis of wheat sensitivity to the ToxB fungal effector from Pyrenophora tritici-repentis, the causal agent of tan spot"                                  
[4] "When time really is money: in situ quantification of the strobilurin resistance mutation G143A in the wheat pathogen Blumeria graminis f. sp. tritici."             
[5] "A detailed in silico analysis of secondary metabolite biosynthesis clusters in the genome of the broad host range plant pathogenic fungus Sclerotinia sclerotiorum."
```

Comment: Thank you, det. I tried the code, however, the result was: character(0)

Comment: I've just copied your text and assinged it to `x` and it gives me correct output.

Comment: I've copied text you provided and assinged it to variable `x` in R: `x <- ...` (of course you need to put the text in quotation in R)

Comment: How do you add str_remove_all("[“”]") to the end of the pipe line?

Comment: `str_extract_all(x, "“.*?”") %>% .[[1]] %>% str_remove_all("[“”]")`

Comment: How do you remove the numbers at the start of the text in the output?

Comment: Numbers are not in actual result, its just that I've copied result from console. It just means that result is vector of length 5.